# Catching all inline css and its html tag

Tags: html, css, legacy-code

I am refactoring legacy code of MVC framework html views. Many, many, many css styles are applied inline, which is bad practice.

Is there a tool to generate a css file from all the inline styles of an html file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072432/generating-a-stylesheet-based-on-inline-html-styling

Comment: Great ! Thank you. Put it in an answer and i will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here: [Generating a stylesheet based on inline HTML styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072432/generating-a-stylesheet-based-on-inline-html-styling)
I couldn't post it as an answer, because it told it was too trivial for an answer.
Maybe now after I added few more lines it will take it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [Inline CSS Extractor](https://github.com/peterlazzarino/Inline-CSS-Extractor), their website is down, but github have the zip file, download it and open it in your local, I believe that will save you loads of time too.